# Binding DP of Control2 to DP of Control1 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

How can I ensure that the `Value` dependency property of my two `UserControls` is consistently updated in my `MainWindow` when I make changes to the property in one of the controls?

**Control1:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlBining.Control1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(string),
        typeof(Control1)
     );

  public string Value
  {
     get => (string)GetValue(ValueProperty);
     set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
  }
```

**Control2:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlBining.Control2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlBining"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(string),
        typeof(Control2)
     );

  public string Value
  {
     get => (string)GetValue(ValueProperty);
     set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
  }
```

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window x:Class="ControlBining.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlBining"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:Control1 Width="100" x:Name="Control1" Value="10"/>
        <local:Control2 Width="100" Value="{Binding ElementName=Control1, Path=Value}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: You have again set the UserControl's DataContext to themselves. As explained in the comments/answers to your previous question, it's wrong to do that.

Comment: Besides that, why don't you bind both controls to a common view model? And what does "*change the Value in control1*" actually  mean? Ary you just typing something into the TextBox while it keeps the focus?

Comment: @Clemens I do not have a ViewModel at the moment. I removed the DataContext and then it does not work at all.

Comment: As you already know, it should be `Text="{Binding Value,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

Comment: @Clemens I tried this with two simple TextBoxes without any viewModel and it works., but not with the custom controls.

Comment: @Clemens Oh, you mean I should set it per element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserControl should not set its own DataContext, because doing so breaks any DataContext based Bindings of its dependency propertises. Instead, use a RelativeSource Binding in its XAML:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If you want to update the `Value` property while you are typing into the TextBox, also set this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

When you also want to type into Control2, make the Value Binding TwoWay:

```
<local:Control2 Value="{Binding ElementName=Control1, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

or make the Value property bind TwoWay by default:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Value), typeof(string), typeof(Control2),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Comment: How can I set this part from Code-behind `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}` There are cases where I need to bind in code-behind. I think Source = this is wrong correct?

Comment: `Source = this` should work. A common workaround to avoid multiple RelativeSource Bindings is to set `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"` on the top level Panel in the control's XAML.

Comment: That is even better. Thanks again. So not the UserControl itself but a level down?